# Deny remove some rows from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I need your help.

I have table test where 3 columns `[Id], [Status], [Student]`.

I want to create a trigger which denies delete rows where status is 3.

How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Go through this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189799.aspx first

Comment: add `where status !=3` to your `delete` statement

Comment: Or work with a view that filters the rows by this field, not directly against the table.

Comment: Like this: CREATE TRIGGER DeleteStatus ON test INSTEAD OF DELETE  where status !=3

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There's absolutely no reason to and various reasons *not to*. Triggers aren't meant to do that. If you want to limit the actions of users, abstract the tables and use views and stored procedures. You'll also  confuse everyone using the table by this unexpected behavior.

Comment: Magic numbers suck. Why `3` and not `937`? Your users should only be able to delete stuff through scripts you create e.g. stored procedures. Wrap your logic in there and if you insist on using the magic number, put a useful comment in the code explaining why!

Comment: This sounds like an attempt to implement row-level security. There other techniques to implement just that in SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the table and trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Id int PRIMARY KEY,
    Status int NOT NULL,
    Student varchar(100) NOT NULL

)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER DeletingStatus3TestIsNotAllowed
ON Test FOR DELETE
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted WHERE Status = 3)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Deleting rows with Status = 3 is not allowed', 16, -1)
        ROLLBACK
    END
GO
```

Disclaimer: implementing this busines rule using triggers is probably not a good idea

Comment: the trigger code also needs a ROLLBACK; the RAISERROR alone will not prevent the delete.

Comment: This should have been an INSTEAD OF trigger. Then you wouldn't need RAISEERROR or ROLLBACK. In any case, this statement will terminate all deletes if they touch even a single row with the wrong status. If the OP wants row-level security, there are far better options